# How to extract the value of a textfield with the square root sign? Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, uitextfield, square-root

I have a program that calculates a certain set of equations. The user inputs the numbers into a UITextField and the program calculates it for them. I wanted to give the user the option to insert a square root instead of having to figure out the exact value of the square root first.

**My Issue:** 
When I try to extract the float value of the textField via:

```
    floatNumber = [[textField text] floatValue];
```

The textField with the square root returns a 0. Is there a way I could extract the number with the square root?

Thanks,
Neil.

Comment: Give an example of the entered text that returns `0`.

Comment: If i would input something like "√2"

Comment: `floatValue` does not evaluate math symbols, just numbers. Since the text doesn't start with a digit, you get back 0. You would need to detect the square root symbol yourself, strip it off, get the number, then use the `sqrt` function yourself to calculate the answer.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought.... Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `√` may be embedded in an equation...
You'll want to find the location of the `√` inside your string. That will be the start of your range. The length of your range will be defined by the location + the count of numbers that follow. If you only want the numbers then just increase the location by 1.

You'll have edges cases to handle but this is a start:

```
    NSString *equation = @"(√646474)";

    NSRange rangeOfSqrRoot = [equation rangeOfString:@"√"];

    rangeOfSqrRoot = NSMakeRange(rangeOfSqrRoot.location + 1, (equation.length - 1) - rangeOfSqrRoot.location);
    __block NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];

    NSRange rangeOfNonNumber = [equation rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[charSet invertedSet] options:NSLiteralSearch range:rangeOfSqrRoot];

    rangeOfSqrRoot = NSMakeRange(rangeOfSqrRoot.location, rangeOfNonNumber.location - 2);

    __block NSMutableString *numbers = [NSMutableString string];
    [equation enumerateSubstringsInRange:rangeOfSqrRoot options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {

        NSRange r = [substring rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
        if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
            [numbers appendString:substring];
        } else {
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@", numbers);

output: 646474
```

---

Also, have you tried using `NSExpression` to handle your math operations?
http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/

ex:

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"4 + 5 - 2**3"];
NSLog(@"%@", [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]);
```

Note: You cant do `[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"√25"]`.
You'll get: `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "√25 == 1"'`